# Keyboard layout to input a specific code

Tags: keyboard, games, keyboard-layout

I'm playing on a betting site where I have to enter a game number then select a specific result.

Each result can be entered by typing a code of keys.

For example, the result `1X/X`  can be selected by just  typing `1KO8` and not scrolling the whole possible results to find the wanted one.

Is it possible to create a keyboard layout and manipulate the keys input to type a result directly.

Comment: Is this an advertisement?

Comment: I don't really understand this question... Do you want a shortcut that enters a set of keys? Or do you want certain keys closer together?

Comment: @Tim    shortcut that enters a set of keys

Comment: Simple. Add a shortcut with the command `xdotool key 1; xdotool key K; xdotool key O; xdotool key 8`.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the cross platform .NET rewrite of the popular Windows AutoHotkey scripting language, called IronAHK. I save time every day on my Windows system with AHK, cutting keystrokes and saving mouse clicks here and there.

You can check it out here:

⠀http://www.ironahk.net/

And you should check out the original AHK as IronAHK doesn't market themselves to the extent of the original.

⠀http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: This should help you get your feet wet: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm